# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_X f_nd\mu=\int\limits_X fd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ is a measurable space and $f_n,g_n,f,g$ are all measurable functions defined on $X$. The following conditions are satisfied:

(i) $f_n\to f\;\&\;g_n\to g$ almost everywhere on $X$

(ii) $|f_n|\leq g_n$ and $\int\limits_X g_nd\mu<\infty\;\forall\; n\geq1$

(iii) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_X g_nd\mu=\int\limits_X gd\mu<\infty$

Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_X f_nd\mu=\int\limits_X fd\mu$.

Attempt at answer:

I know that since $f_n,g_n,f,g$ are all measurable, then $|f_n|,|g_n|,|f|,|g|$ are all measurable. Also that $f_n\to f\;\&\;g_n\to g$ almost everywhere on $X$ implies $f_n\to f\;\&\;g_n\to g$ almost uniform convergence on $X$ implies $f_n\to f\;\&\;g_n\to g$ in measure on $X$.

It's almost like "Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Thm", but I have "almost everyhwere" convergence. Does that make a difference, or am I just making up differences where there are none? Any help/advice would be remarkably useful.

Comment: Your result is effectively the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. Almost everywhere convergence (for the purposes of Lebesgue) is the same as regular convergence since the points at which they do not agree is a set of measure zero and these differences won't be picked up by the Lebesgue integral. So you can think of this statement as a slightly more general version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use Fatou's lemma with the sequences $(g_n-f_n,n\geqslant 1)$ and $(g_n+f_n,n\geqslant 1)$.

Note that when $g_n=g$ for all $n$, it's exactly the dominated convergence theorem. This gives a generalization.

Comment: I thought Fatou's Lemma required non-negative sequences.

Comment: So are these sequences, or I missed something? (yes, it does require non-negativeness)

Comment: Why do you think they're non-negative?

Comment: Nevermind...I'm just frazzled and missing the painfully obvoius. Thank you! ^_^

Comment: No problem, the devil is in the details so you are right to check everything is fine.